# Grunt Live Reload after File Upload

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, gruntjs, livereload

I am using:

- Grunt with the watch plugin for live reload &
- Sublime Text 2's SFTP plugin for uploading files on save

Live reload is just a little quicker than the SFTP upload.

Using Guard, you could set a grace_period to delay the live reload. Is there an equivalent feature/work-around for Grunt?

Comment: Just peeked at the source code and it doesn't look like this a feature yet. [Here is the source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/tasks/lib/taskrun.js#L77-L83) where it kicks of `livreload`. It wouldn't be very hard to add the feature I'd guess. File an issue on GitHub perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grunt-ftp-deploy](https://github.com/zonak/grunt-ftp-deploy) with watch plugin instead of relying on Sublime Text . That way you could synchronize your actions .

```
npm install grunt-ftp-deploy
```

**Usage Example :**

```
ftp-deploy: {
    build: {
        auth: {
             host: 'server.com',
             port: 21,
             authKey: 'key1'
        },
        src: 'path/to/source/folder',
        dest: '/path/to/destination/folder'
   }
}
```